# Inferring whether an integer/string is a unix timestamp

Tags: python, unix

Let's say I have a list of different integers (either as integers, or as strings), such as:

```
1,2,100,84,12,109
```

I know with a fair degree of accuracy that this **probably not** a unix timestamp series. However, with the following series of numbers, I would estimate that it probably would be:

```
1446250200, 1446250220, 1446240220
```

Is there a good way to estimate whether a list of integers is most likely a unix timestamp series? I need to have a function like this for date parsing -- one which guesses whether the field is an integer or a timstamp (and if it guesses incorrectly the user can override that). What would this function look like?

Comment: Why is 1,2,100,84,12,109 probably not a unix timestamp series? Do you not consider January 1970 as a real time?

Comment: This seems pretty under constrained.  Why isn't the first sequence a valid sequence of timestamps?  The best you can do is see if they fit into a sequence of times that is reasonable for your application ... I suppose you could also check the ranges to see if they are grouped (but again, do you expect them to be grouped?)

Comment: @mgilson -- I understand it's **possible** that the first item is a unix time series. What I'm trying to do is make an educated guess as to whether it is most likely unix timestamps or just a numerical field. I would make an educated guess that the first series has a greater probably of not being a unix timestamp series and being a plain numeric field (using actual data entered by a user).

Comment: @David542 -- I understand that, but we have nowhere near enough information to make an __educated__ guess.  Depending on your application, perhaps the first sequence is more likely to be  timestamps (e.g. if you're processing data from 1970)

Comment: 1) define which dates you consider to be "actual dates", whatever that means. 2) check whether possible timestamps all fall within the range. 3) let the user correct the (probably large) amount of wrong guesses.

Comment: Do you have any corpus of already-decided date sequences vs integer sequences to work from? You could feed them into SpamBayes and see what happens...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler -- thank you, that's a good idea.